# Como capturar los comandos realizados atraves de una sesion remota

Tags: linux, windows, ssh

¿Hay alguna manera de capturar localmente lo q escriba en el una sesion remota (SSH) sin instalar nada en el servidor?

Necesito saber si hay algun metodo donde pueda capturar y guardar localmente en un archivo de texto plano todos los comandos utilizados atraves de una conexion remota a un servidor y a su vez saber que archivos fueron modificados en dicha sesion. ¿Alguna sugerencia al respecto?.

Comment: A primera instancia se me ocurre que copies el archivo `.bash_history` del usuario en la sesión remota. Otra idea es usar un keylogger. Otra es usar el depurador GDB; pero esto se me hace muy complicado para lo que yo sé.

Comment: Ohh gracias, voy a probar con esas opciones a ver como me va.